# Decrypting aes-256 on GPU

Tags: cryptography

I basically want to run this command below on a GPU instead of a CPU for maximum speed, what language would be the simplest to write such a task in? I was thinking python with PYcuda but it gets a bit out my depth.

```
openssl enc -d -p -aes-256-cbc -a -in \<ciphertext file\> -out \<plaintext file\> -pass pass:\<password\>
```

Comment: A GPU may not be faster, most recent CPUs have special instructions to speed up encryption, some even have full-on hardware encryption.

Comment: @RyanVincent What happened to the hamsters, are they OK?

Comment: @zaph, I take good care of them - I don't get to do anything if they are upset :)

Comment: I have a couple of cats, Obie and Luci, that would like to be "friends" with them, do they date?

Comment: @zaph, I was told decrypting I can get speeds of up to 100x increase.. also I notice that you're into bitcoin and my basic objective here is to crack an old multibit key file I have that has like 3btc in it..

Comment: You are surely right but.. I look at hashcat and oclhashcat and the difference in speed is major for some of there aes256 algos, I don't understand cryptography much so yea.. P.S I'm sure you're a handsome man :D

Comment: Hashing is not encryption, AES is encryption–that are different things. There are data throughput issues in encryption.

Comment: Yes I understand that.. but in oclhashcat, they have algos that include encryption where I can get like 1million passwords a second and on my CPU program I get about 100k/s

Comment: Ah, password cracking. Hashing is not encryption and oclhashcat does not support AES or any encryption, just hashing.

Comment: Okay so my CPU is the fastest way... least I learned something today. thank you Mr zaph.

Comment: The GPU may be faster, may not. The issue is that the question and comments, small animals aside, is that the question is vague with "I heard" references and mixes-up hashing with encryption.

Comment: Zaph.. you know multibit? and the exported private keys? that is aes-256-cbc right?

Comment: multiunit seems to be using AES to encrypt exported keys. Not sure how that relates to the question but you will not successfully decrypt an AES encrypted file by brute-forcing the encryption key. Also there is a problem of knowing when the correct password has been tried. Also a problem with how the key was derived from the password.

Comment: It is an entirely different problem that attacking passwords which is usually done by trying passwords from frequent password lists. And in the cases where passwords have been hashed correctly with an iteration count it may be to time consuming to be successful.

Comment: It uses password-based key derivation.. not sure if that is why it works so well.. but like that openssl command, it is able to identify if the password is correct or not, otherwise it throws a "decrypt error" problem, I don't expect to bruteforce it either.. just using a password list.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?  what did you wind up doing?